# AngularJS - Pagination not rendering on $scope.Watch change (CodePen included)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

**Question Background:**

I'm learning AngularJS. I have created a simple app that takes in 3 form inputs, and on submission of this form a paginated list should be rendered. I have a dependancy on UI-Bootstrap. This is a Plnkr showing the pagination example I'm attempting to incorporate into my app: http://plnkr.co/edit/81fPZxpnOQnIHQgp957q?p=preview

**The Issue & Demo:**

This is the link to my code so far on CodePen:

http://codepen.io/daveharris/pen/NNMQyy

I have a list of 1000 items populating on my `SearchingService` model that is injected and shared between the two controllers.

I cannot get the paginated `ng-repeat` to populate when the `searchingService.searchList` list on the `SearchingService` model is changed,
It is as if the `$scope.Watch` is not being triggered.

Any help getting to the bottom of this will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As bchemy pointed out, `$watch` should be changed to `$watchCollection`. But this change won't be enough to have your app working correctly with your current code, since the pagination looks broken.

You should also add another watcher to control the pagination as the one in the example that you want to replicate:

```
$scope.$watch('currentPage + numPerPage', function() {
    var begin = (($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.numPerPage)
    , end = begin + $scope.numPerPage;

    $scope.filteredItems = $scope.searchingService.searchList.slice(begin, end);
  });
```

Also `$scope.items` array was getting duplicate `searchLists` in it and would mess the pagination length.

I have created this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/CqeLoZWuPh0VxhntQUQ1?p=preview) where you can see your example fully working.

Answer (score 5):

Change line 31 from `$watch` to `$watchCollection`. Since your service is mutating the array (via `.push`), the reference stays the same, so the `$watch` won't trigger. `$watchCollection` will watch references to the array *members* rather than the reference to the *array* itself.